# Why does VirtualBox crash if I close Ubuntu one way but not if I close Ubuntu another way?

Tags: shutdown

I am running Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit as a guest on a Windows 7 Sony Vaio laptop (64-bit). Here is what happens:

I start up Ubuntu via the VirtualBox manager (by clicking start)- it runs in scale mode to start out (windowed mode). In this scale mode, I have two options to close Ubuntu:

1)Click the "X" in the upper right-hand corner of the Ubuntu window and just close it like a normal window. A menu pops up with 3 options: a)Save the machine state; b)Send the shutdown signal; and c)Power off the machine.

If I choose option 'c', the window just closes and Ubuntu is no more- I am back in my host Windows 7 environment.

2)The second option I have is by clicking the power symbol while in Ubuntu (which is right below the "X" that closes out the window). When I click "shutdown", I get an error message from Oracle VM VirtualBox Manager: "Orcale VM VirtualBox Manager has stopped working."

It searches for a solution, but does not find one, and the only option I have is to "close program."

So why does closing Ubuntu by "sending the shutdown signal" crash VirtualBox but if I simply close the Ubuntu window by "x"ing out of it, and click "power down machine," I have no problems?

P.S. I can also post the VBox log if that will help ID the root of this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Option C is basically like pressing and holding the power button on the virtual machine. It's not a proper shutdown, is never recommended as the "normal" way to shutdown, and you could end up losing data or with an unbootable VM if you're unlucky.

The other way (from within Ubuntu) is correct, but it appears that Virtualbox has a problem with the signals Ubuntu sends upon shutdown. Does it crash immediately after, or do you see Ubuntu beginning shutdown first? In any case, this alternative is better than the power off because Ubuntu probably gets partly shutdown.

To fix it, try updating Virtualbox and/or include vbox logs.

Comment: Hey izx- I restarted my computer, and now the problem is gone (don't really know why). I found this through another Google search also: https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/8316

The individual there had a problem similar to mine, and it appeared to be caused by the host's graphics drivers. Mine are all up-to-date, so I don't think that is what was causing the problem. When I restarted my computer, I think it changed something in Windows because when Oracle VBox crashed, Windows stated that it was "changing compatibility settings" to work better with VBox, so the restart may have been that. Thnx!

Comment: Also, I trust that I have not damaged Ubuntu or VBox by clicking the "power-off" option in the past. I think I probably used that method about 10 times or so, but Ubuntu and VBox appear to be working fine now, which is great because I finally have Ubuntu up and running like a champ on my system! Yay!

Comment: Good to know. Did you reboot the computer after the initial vbox installation? That has caused problems for me in the past (i.e., not rebooting and trying to run a VM straight away).

Comment: Sorry- I keep forgetting to up arrow and accept answers. But regarding whether I rebooted after installing VBox, I honestly can't remember (I think I might have). Thanks for the help again!